# Closest implementation for enums with fields in pyO3

Tags: rust, pyo3

As of PyO3 version 0.18.1, only fieldless enums are supported.

What are the potential implementations to support enums with fields using PyO3 if implemented manually?? `pyclass` is of no use here (Correct me if I am wrong).

For instance if I have to implement for following enum?

```rust
pub enum Prop {
    Str(String),
    I32(i32),
    I64(i64),
    U32(u32),
    U64(u64),
    F32(f32),
    F64(f64),
    Bool(bool),
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/discussions/2959

Answer (score 1):

Copied from github.

> The problem with this approach is that its not very pythonic. It would only be ideal if user could provide list of Prop as dictionary instead. I have managed to implement it as follows:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(FromPyObject, Debug)]
pub enum Prop {
    Int(usize),
    String(String),
    Vec(Vec<usize>),
}

#[pyfunction]
pub fn get_props(props: HashMap<String, Prop>) -> PyResult<()> {
    let v = props.into_iter().collect::<Vec<(String, Prop)>>();
    for i in v {
        println!("K = {}, V = {:?}", i.0, i.1)
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

From python:

```py
import pyo3_example

pyo3_example.get_props({
                   "name": "Shivam Kapoor", 
                   "age": 35,  
                   "hobbies": [1, 2, 3]
                 })
# K = name, V = String("Shivam Kapoor")
# K = age, V = Int(35)
# K = hobbies, V = Vec([1, 2, 3])
```